# Get the label text with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get the text inside a label through jquery. But I've only managed to get the entire html input to show. Where I'd like to just get the text.

I generate a label with a checkbox in a loop as shown below:

```
for (var key in data['results']){ 

    SearchResultsOutter = $('<div />', {
    'class' : 'SearchResultsOutter',
    }).appendTo('.searchresultswrapper');

    paraCheck = $('<label />').html(data['results'][key])
    .prepend($('<input/>').attr({ type: 'checkbox', 'class': 'SearchResultsSibling'}));

    paraCheck.appendTo(SearchResultsOutter)
}
```

And once I click a button I'd like to get the text of the label, through this click event:

```
$('.searchresultcontrol1').on('click', function(){
        console.log('Here');
        outter = $('.searchresultswrapper');

        var lst = [];

        outter.children('div').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('input').is(":checked")){
                lbl = $(this).find('label').html();
                console.log(lbl);
            }      
        });
    });
```

But I've only managed to get the console to print out:

[image]

I have tried to use `val()` but it does not print out anything

I'd like to get just:

```
   (CDI.L) Candover Investments plc, LSE (Asset Management) 
   (YVI.MI) Valore Italia Holding di Partecipazioni S.p.A., MIL (Asset Management)
```

Comment: How does your markup look like? You should try using `.text()` instead of `.html()` so you will only get the text node.

Comment: @Terry text worked! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment: use `.text()` instead of `.html()`. The difference between the two is that the former gets the combined text within the selector, while latter gets the HTML content.

In this case, you would want to use `.text()` so that you leave out the `<input>` child DOM node.